# Using form_tag to create a button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

So I have this code in my views to create a button that approves all 5 star reviews. The issue I'm facing is that `button_to` doesn't hide the params and order_ids is about 200 order objects. So when I click on the button, I get the error

`Request-URI Too Large WEBrick::HTTPStatus::RequestURITooLarge`

I think I need to use the `form_tag` helper but I'm not too sure how to make a button with `form_tag`. Or how to link the two things.

```
<div style="margin: 0 0 50px 0">
  <%= button_to "Approve reviews with 5 stars",
    { action: :approve_reviews, order_ids: @orders, rating: 5 }
    , method: :post %>
</div>
```

Comment: You can add `params:{}` in the end. Like `params: {order_ids: @orders}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend doing it this way -

1. It is a bad idea to send so much data through the URL
2. Have a `form` and a hidden field that contains the values for the order IDs (and probably Rating, unless you have your routes configured for it)
3. Have a simple button that just submits the form when clicked

   ```
   <%= form_tag({ :action => :approve_reviews }) do -%>
       <%= hidden_field_tag :order_ids, :value => @orders %>
       <%= hidden_field_tag :rating, :value => 5 %>
       <%= submit_tag "Approve reviews with 5 stars" %>
    <% end -%>
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add `params:{}` in the end to `your button_to`

`<%= button_to "Approve reviews with 5 stars", action: :approve_reviews, params: {order_ids: @orders, rating: 5} %>`

Note: by default the method will be post so you don't have to specify the method.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<%= form_tag({ action: :approve_reviews, rating: 5 }) do -%>
  <%= hidden_field_tag 'order_ids', @orders %>
  <%= submit_tag 'Approve reviews with 5 stars' %>
<%= end -%>
```